# How to specify different CFLAGS to different platform using Android.mk

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

I need to build a library for both `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` platform, on `armeabi-v7a`.

I need `LOCAL_CFLAGS="-O3 -mfpu=neon"`, however on x86 I only need `LOCAL_CFLAGS="-O3"` since `-mfpu=neon` is not supported.

How to do that without using different `Android.mk` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the value of `$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)` and use the `ifeq` syntax:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS="-O3 -mfpu=neon"
else
    LOCAL_CFLAGS="-O3"
endif
```